# API access to Craft 3

Tags: craft3

Does anyone know if there is an API for CRAFT 3 where I can authenticate to and query (CRUD) all the elements (channels, etc.) I have created on it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look at the [headless documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/headless.html) which offers a few solutions / ways such as a GraphQL API, REST-API & a JSON API

Comment: I have tried to use the rest api but I cant make it work. Do you have any link or tutorial for getting to work?

Comment: You can try this tutorial/video out to get started https://mijingo.com/blog/what-is-the-element-api-in-craft-cms. It is for an older version, but still holds up rather well. You will have to define the routes that you want and it is only designed for read access.

Comment: What if I want to change (update) the something in the DB?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, neither the Element API plugin nor the native Craft GraphQL implementation supports writes or updates.

It is on the Craft 4.0 backlog to have mutations support in the native GraphQL implementation. https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/4835

There is a 3rd party CraftQL plugin that does support mutations.

If you want the ability to write in a REST context, I'd suggest watching this video: https://dotall.com/sessions/how-to-create-a-full-rest-api-with-craft-3

Comment: Also there is a sample project for the REST setup here: https://github.com/flipboxlabs/craft-restful-project